# Flutter & Stream : The getter 'name' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, provider

I am trying to fetch a data from firebase. But I encountered an error.
Notice that although there is an error, I still got the data. Why an error appear before/yet I get the data? Why is that? How do I fix it?

Main Code :

```
final loginUser = Provider.of<AllUser>(context);
print('user data : ${loginUser.name}');
```

Function :

```
Stream<AllUser> get loginUserData {
    DocumentReference reference = userCollection.document(uid);
    final Stream<DocumentSnapshot> snapshots = reference.snapshots();
    return snapshots.map(
      (snapshot) => AllUser(
          name: snapshot.data['name'] ?? '',
          email: snapshot.data['email'] ?? '',
          uid: snapshot.data['uid'] ?? '',
          signInMethod: snapshot.data['signInMethod'] ?? '',
          locale: snapshot.data['locale'] ?? '',
          score: '2000'),
    );
  }
```

Error Message :

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building ProfileSetting(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<SystemUser>, _InheritedProviderScope<AllUser>, MediaQuery], state: _ProfileSettingState#48449):
The getter 'name' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: name

The relevant error-causing widget was
    ProfileSetting 
lib/…/profile_setting/profile_wrapper.dart:19
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _ProfileSettingState.build 
package:PhotoEarn/…/profile_setting/profile_setting.dart:38
#2      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4758
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4641
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4813
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (19228): user data : King of Light
```

I am looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what Streams are. Your model above doesn't need to use them. Remove Stream<AllUser> and change it to AllUser

Comment: Could you show me how?

Comment: Change Stream<AllUser> to AllUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as a community wiki as this was suggested by @Uni in the comments.

You model is not using Streams so all you have to do is change the your `loginUserData` functions to have the following format:

```
AllUser get loginUserData {
    ...
}
```

---

Edit:

Posting the whole code, also since you get only 1 document in your query you do not need to iterate on an array of documents, so the code could look like:

```
Future<AllUser> get loginUserData async{
    DocumentReference reference = userCollection.document(uid);
    var document = await reference.get();
    return new allUser(
      name: document.data['name'] ?? '',
      email: document.data['email'] ?? '',
      uid: document.data['uid'] ?? '',
      signInMethod: document.data['signInMethod'] ?? '',
      locale: document.data['locale'] ?? '',
      score: '2000');
}
```

Comment: It gave me an error. Could you write the whole code?

Comment: I edited the answer and changed the code a bit to make it simpler